# trying to get generic list property value but gives me an exception

Tags: c#, list, generics

I'm trying to get the value of a custom class with `List<T>` properties, however it throws an exception (Object does not match target type.).

I want to check first if the value is `Null` if not then process the value.

**Model:**

```
public class CustomModel
{
    public List<Foo> FooList { get; set; }

    public List<Bar> BarList { get; set; }

}
```

**Codes for processing the model data:**

```
public class Result<T>
{
    private readonly T _model;

    public Result(T model)
    {
        _model = model;
    }

    private CustomObject CreateSomething(T model)
    {
        var obj = new CustomObject();

        var type = model.GetType();
        var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            if (property.PropertyType.IsGenericType && 
                typeof(List<>).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()))
            {

                //this throws an error
                var testList = property.GetValue(this, new object[] { });

                //processed value will be passed to object

                //some codes here after getting the property value

            }
        }

        return obj;
    }
}
```

How do I get the value so I can process them?

Comment: Just tested your code and it works fine

Comment: it does not on my end. it throws an exception: `Object does not match target type.`

Comment: Can you provide more code then, at list relevant part of this class that is referenced by keyword `this` (not all properties just a 'short version')

Comment: @Fabjan just updated the question

Comment: This example shows that your code works well : http://rextester.com/SSUG99493

Comment: Are you sure you passing the right object instance?  this here? in `property.GetValue(this, new object[] { });`

Comment: It should be `var testList = property.GetValue(FooList, new object[] { });`  <-- FooList

Comment: @Fabjan i have a different structure in the code but then I copied the what is in your link. Still does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a typo? The property is read from this instead of the model:

```
var testList = property.GetValue(model, new object[] { });
                                 ^^^^^
```

Comment: my bad. It should be the model to get the value of a property without exception.

Answer (score 1):

You should make the `List<>` to a generic type with `MakeGenericType()`.

Something like:

```
var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new[]{typeof(T)});
if (property.PropertyType.IsGenericType 
  && listType.IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()))
```

More info on MakeGenericType: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype

---

`var testList = property.GetValue(this, new object[] { });`

Are you sure you passing the right object instance?  `this` here?

It should be `var testList = property.GetValue(FooList, new object[] { });`  <-- FooList

Comment: I'm getting an exception: `Object does not match target type.`